# Vaadin Openlayers Wrapper maximum zoom level for google maps layer is not achieved

Tags: google-maps, zooming, openlayers, vaadin

I hope somebody already had (and solved) this problem since I searched a lot for a solution with no success.

The thing is I have a GoogleHybridMapLayer and a OpenStreetMapLayer, with the google hybrid I can only reach 2 or 3 levels less of zoom then what I get with OSM or going directly to google maps api on other apps. I even tested it on the openlayers google maps demos and they fully zoom in, so I assume it is a problem with the vaadin addon.

I tried everything i could think of and find on the web, including setting the setJsMapOptions params on the OpenLayersMap like this:

```
map.setJsMapOptions("{projection: "
                + "new OpenLayers.Projection(\"EPSG:102113\"),"
                + "units: \"m\","
                + "numZoomLevels: 20,"
                + "maxResolution: 156543.0339, "
                + "maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508, -20037508,20037508, 20037508.34)}");
```

This is crucial for our application since the user is required to set points that are very close to each other.

So, how can I achieve the same zoom level on openlayers wrapper addon than on reqular openlayer google maps?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Matti Tahvonen](https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/2461489#_19_message_2463643) was kind enough to help me out with this issue by increasing the zoom level in the native client method that I did not see.

The latest version in the [svn repo has this fix available](http://code.google.com/p/vopenlayers/source/detail?r=212)

Dont forget to recompile the widget.